# How to use fgetc() to capture only letters and storing input to an array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write an indexing program where it will take input from the user and store it into an array then keep counting the occurrence of words for example.

user enters: hello@#world I,I,I am@#!stuck201

hello 1 occurred 1 time

world 1 occurred 1 time

I occurred 3 times

am occurred 1 time

stuck occurred 1 time

So as you can see it will count anything that contains letter(s) separated by anything as a word.

(I am confused on how to go about checking the input for anything other than letters, I was thinking of using ASCII codes but there has to be a better way, if you could just set me in the correct direction for this, Thank you much.)

Before I began the program I was trying to get I/O working and I am having difficulty. The actual program will require me to use 2 dimensional arrays, but if you could help me with this snippet of code that will be appreciated thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

        char array[64];
        int i=0, j, input;

        printf("Please enter an input:");

        input==fgetc(stdin);
        while(input != " ")
        {
                array[i]==input;
                i++;
                input==fgetc(stdin);
        }

        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {

                printf("You entered:%c",array[j]);


        }
}
```

Upon compilation it gives me a warning "12:14 warning: comparison between pointer and integer"

Output of this code:::

Please enter an input: (I type input) ehehasd world hello (enter)

then it just sits at blank cursor and I have to exit using CTRL C

I want this snippet of code to just take input from user that is separated by a space store it into an array then print out what the user entered. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line (which appears twice in the code):

```
input==fgetc(stdin);
```

makes a comparison, not an assignment.  Use:

```
input = fgetc(stdin);
```

Your line:

```
while(input != " ")
```

is incorrect and is the source of the compiler warning.  You are comparing a string with a character.  You probably intended to use:

```
while (input != ' ')
```

and since you could encounter EOF, you probably should use:

```
while (input != EOF && input != ' ')
```

You could sensibly use `#include <ctype.h>` and then:

```
while (isalpha(input))
```

which automatically handles EOF (it's a valid input to `isalpha()`, but returns false; EOF is not an alphabetic character).

Your final loop should probably be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

(assuming you have a C99 or more recent compiler — if not, declare `j` outside the loop as now).  This only outputs words that have been entered.  Otherwise, you'll be printing undefined gibberish.

You'll need to upgrade the code to handle multiple words in the input.  At the moment, it stops at the end of the first word (assuming you fix the other problems that I've identified).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help...everything you said was spot on, if you don't mind I am going to continue working on this and if I have a question that I absolutely cannot solve myself can I ask you directly?

Comment: On the whole, it would be better to either update the question or ask a new question.  If you update the question, leave the original code intact and add the new code.  Add a comment here to get my attention.

Comment: Hi Jonathan I am completely lost, point blank, I do not know how to move forward on this problem, I have posted a new question, your input will be a great help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085900/how-to-count-unique-number-of-words-using-fgetc-then-printing-the-count-in-c

Comment: You've got a helpful answer over there — not a complete handholding answer, but a helpful one.  If you're not yet familiar with dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` et al) and linked lists, then say so, as a comment to the answer ("Thank you, but I've not yet learned about dynamic memory allocation and linked lists yet, so I need to use a 2D array of characters" or something similar), and update the question to clarify that too.

Comment: Will do because none of that made sense..thanks for helping me on the use of this site as well as my questions because I have gotten a lot of down votes on previous questions.

Comment: At this point I feel like I am just nagging but I don't think that Mauricio will answer in terms of 2D arrays, I am not asking for straight up and down completed code I just need a path on which I can work. My issue is I understand 2D arrays but I don't know how I can store any letters separated by non-alpha as whole words and I don't understand how to implement a counter for each unique word. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'll have a bash at it.  I had to chase children to bed and try to feed a snake — just routine distractions.

Comment: I seriously appreciate it, never have met anyone this helpful on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Check [isalpha](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/), it has some fineprints about what it will consider a letter, but it may work for your case.

Another way to do it, if you don't want to do the loop yourself is to use regular expressions. It is fairly easy to make a regex that returns only sequences of letters.

Answer (score 0):

Use isAlpha() to test is it is a letter, [look here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isalpha.htm)