# How to count unique number of words using fgetc() then printing the count in C

Tags: c, arrays, fgetc

I have asked a question related to this program but now after much research and headbutting I am stuck...again.

I am trying to write a program that will take the user input and store it then print out all the unique words and the number of times they each occurred

for example

```
Please enter something: Hello#@Hello# hs,,,he,,whywhyto[then the user hits enter] 

hello 2 
hs 1 
he 1 
whywhyto 1
```

The above should be the output, of course whywhyto isn't a word but it doesn't matter in this case because I am assuming any pattern of letters separated by anything that isn't a letter (spaces, 0-9,#$(@ etc.) is considered a word. I need to use 2D arrays because I am not capable of using linked lists nor do I understand them yet.

This is all I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <ctype.h> 

int main() 
{ 
char array[64]; 

int i=0, j, input; 

printf("Please enter an input:"); 


input=fgetc(stdin); 

while(input != '\n')
{ 
if(isalpha(input)) 
{ 


array[i]=input; 
i++; 
} 

input=fgetc(stdin); 
} 

for(j=0;j<i;j++) 
{ 
// printf("%c ",j,array[j]); 
printf("%c",array[j]); 
} 
printf("\n"); 
}
```

I am using `isalpha` to get only letters but all this does is it gets rid of anything that isn't a letter, stores it and then prints back, but I have not a clue on how to get it to store words once  for their first occurrence and then just increment a count for each word. I can only use fgetc() which is hard for me at least, I only have about 3-4 months of C experience, I know I will have to use 2 dimensional arrays, have been reading up on them but I have not been able to comprehend how I will implement them please help me out a bit.

Comment: suggest struct mywords { char * pWord; int count; struct mywords* next }  then, for each word read, if that word is not already in the linked list of mywords, then malloc another struct mywords, link it to the end of the existing array of mywords and fill in the values.  setting count to 1 and next to 0, however, if the word is already in the linked list,  then increment the count for that instance of the struct mywords.  After inputting all the words, the step through the linked list, printing the word and the count.  When all done, free first the word then the instance of the struct

Comment: since no linked lists, then define your 2x array: struct myarray{ char word[64]; int count; }  and struct myarray wordArray = null;  int totaluniquewordcounter = 0; Then when the first word is recognized/input to your buffer, then totaluniquewordcounter++; realloc( wordArray, totaluniquewordcounter*sizeof(struct myarray) ); then wordArray[totaluniquewordcount-1]->count = 0; etc.

Comment: Could you possibly put together something like a previous post did, an outline code using 2d arrays instead of linked lists like he did??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code that seems to work:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAX_WORDS = 64, MAX_WORD_LEN = 20 };

int main(void)
{
    char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN];
    int  count[MAX_WORDS] = { 0 };
    int w = 0;
    char word[MAX_WORD_LEN];
    int c;
    int l = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (isalpha(c))
        {
            if (l < MAX_WORD_LEN - 1)
               word[l++] = c;
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Word too long: %*s%c...\n", l, word, c);
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (l > 0)
        {
            word[l] = '\0';
            printf("Found word <<%s>>\n", word);
            assert(strlen(word) < MAX_WORD_LEN);
            int found = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            {
                if (strcmp(word, words[i]) == 0)
                {
                    count[i]++;
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                if (w >= MAX_WORDS)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Too many distinct words (%s)\n", word);
                    break;
                }
                strcpy(words[w], word);
                count[w++] = 1;
            }
            l = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
        printf("%3d: %s\n", count[i], words[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./wordfreq <<< "I think, therefore I am, I think, or maybe I do not think after all, and therefore I am not."
Found word <<I>>
Found word <<think>>
Found word <<therefore>>
Found word <<I>>
Found word <<am>>
Found word <<I>>
Found word <<think>>
Found word <<or>>
Found word <<maybe>>
Found word <<I>>
Found word <<do>>
Found word <<not>>
Found word <<think>>
Found word <<after>>
Found word <<all>>
Found word <<and>>
Found word <<therefore>>
Found word <<I>>
Found word <<am>>
Found word <<not>>
  5: I
  3: think
  2: therefore
  2: am
  1: or
  1: maybe
  1: do
  2: not
  1: after
  1: all
  1: and
$ ./wordfreq <<< "I think thereforeIamIthinkormaybeI do not think after all, and therefore I am not."
Found word <<I>>
Found word <<think>>
Word too long: thereforeIamIthinkor...
  1: I
  1: think
$ ./wordfreq <<< "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>                 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>                 aa ab ac ad ae af ag ah ai aj ak al am
>                 an ao ap aq ar as at au av aw ax ay az
>                "
Found word <<a>>
Found word <<b>>
Found word <<c>>
Found word <<d>>
Found word <<e>>
Found word <<f>>
Found word <<g>>
Found word <<h>>
Found word <<i>>
Found word <<j>>
Found word <<k>>
Found word <<l>>
Found word <<m>>
Found word <<n>>
Found word <<o>>
Found word <<p>>
Found word <<q>>
Found word <<r>>
Found word <<s>>
Found word <<t>>
Found word <<u>>
Found word <<v>>
Found word <<w>>
Found word <<x>>
Found word <<y>>
Found word <<z>>
Found word <<A>>
Found word <<B>>
Found word <<C>>
Found word <<D>>
Found word <<E>>
Found word <<F>>
Found word <<G>>
Found word <<H>>
Found word <<I>>
Found word <<J>>
Found word <<K>>
Found word <<L>>
Found word <<M>>
Found word <<N>>
Found word <<O>>
Found word <<P>>
Found word <<Q>>
Found word <<R>>
Found word <<S>>
Found word <<T>>
Found word <<U>>
Found word <<V>>
Found word <<W>>
Found word <<X>>
Found word <<Y>>
Found word <<Z>>
Found word <<aa>>
Found word <<ab>>
Found word <<ac>>
Found word <<ad>>
Found word <<ae>>
Found word <<af>>
Found word <<ag>>
Found word <<ah>>
Found word <<ai>>
Found word <<aj>>
Found word <<ak>>
Found word <<al>>
Found word <<am>>
Too many distinct words (am)
  1: a
  1: b
  1: c
  1: d
  1: e
  1: f
  1: g
  1: h
  1: i
  1: j
  1: k
  1: l
  1: m
  1: n
  1: o
  1: p
  1: q
  1: r
  1: s
  1: t
  1: u
  1: v
  1: w
  1: x
  1: y
  1: z
  1: A
  1: B
  1: C
  1: D
  1: E
  1: F
  1: G
  1: H
  1: I
  1: J
  1: K
  1: L
  1: M
  1: N
  1: O
  1: P
  1: Q
  1: R
  1: S
  1: T
  1: U
  1: V
  1: W
  1: X
  1: Y
  1: Z
  1: aa
  1: ab
  1: ac
  1: ad
  1: ae
  1: af
  1: ag
  1: ah
  1: ai
  1: aj
  1: ak
  1: al
$
```

The test for 'word too long' and 'too many words' help reassure me that the code is sound.  Devising such tests is good practice.

Comment: I'll get back to you tomorrow it's getting late here Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey Jonathan, this code says while the char isn't end of file and if the char is a letter if l is less then 19 then keep storing the input to word[l] else print out the word is too long...etc...I've been trying to get it to where it only accepts a single line of input and once it hits EOF it returns the count and words...would I just put in a big if loop for that to happen?

Comment: It doesn't accept just a single line of input; it accepts any number of lines of input.  You can add a test for newline if you want.  Or, if you really want one line at a time, then use `fgets()` to get the line, then parse the line — probably easier.  You're allowed to do some of the thinking.

Comment: `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help...was able to get a variation to accomplish the same task.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is homework or not so I did not do everything for you, I also cleaned up your code a little bit. But pretty much if you don't have a knowledge of how many words the person may input you need a dynamic data structure such as a linkedlist

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h> 

typedef struct linkedlist linkedlist;
struct linkedlist{
    char *word;
    int count;
    linkedlist *next;
};

int main() 
{ 
    //know your bounds, this will cause trouble if word is longer than 64 chars
    char array[64]; 
    int i=0, input;
    linkedlist *head = NULL;

    printf("Please enter an input:"); 

    while((input=fgetc(stdin)) != '\n')
    { 
        if(isalpha(input) && i!=63) //added this so that code does not brake (word is 64 chars)
        { 
            array[i]=input; 
        }
        else{
            array[i]='\0';
            char *word = malloc(strlen(array)+1);
            strcpy(word, array);
            add_word(word, &head);
            i=0; //need to restart i to keep reading words
        }

        i++;
    } 

    //print out final results
    for(linkedlist *temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next){
        printf("%s %d ", temp->word, temp->count);
    }
}

//adds word to end of list if does not exist
//increments word count if it exists
void add_word(char *word, linkedlist **ll){
    //implement this
}

//frees resources used by malloc (lookup how to free a linkedlist/destroy a linked list
//make sure to free both final and head in main
void destroy_list(linkedlist **ll){
    //implement this
}
```

For add_word you will need something along the lines of (PSEUDO-CODE):

```
list = *ll
if(list == NULL): //new list
    *ll = malloc(sizeof(linkedlist))
    ll->word = word
    ll->count = 1
    ll->next = NULL
    return

while list->next != null:
    if word = list->word:
        free(word)
        list->count++
        return
    list = list->next

if list->word = word: //last word in list
    free(word)
    list->count++
else: //word did not exist, add new word to end of list
    temp = malloc(sizeof(linkedlist))
    temp->word = word
    temp->count = 1
    list->next = temp
```

Maybe not the most efficient way but you can improve upon it
Hope I did not confuse you further, good luck

Comment: Not bad, but surely it would be better to have the `add_word()` function scan the list to see whether the word is already in the list, and increment the count if so, and add the word to the list with a count of one if it is not in the list. The node could be added at either end of the list with almost equal facility. It might be best to pass `array` (rather than a copy of it) to the `add_word()` function, leaving it to the list management code to make the copy if the word does not exist.  Otherwise, the `add_word()` code needs to free the word passed in if it is already found in the list.

Comment: you are right, checking if the word is there originally would be a much better approach, I was thinking originally (before I came up with count_words) an add to front would be easier for him to implement but he would have to traverse the list and delete nodes in count_words, so your approach is better. I will update it

Comment: This is way far out of my understanding I do not know how to use linked lists...I can better grasp the use of 2 dimensional arrays for this problem if you wouldn't mind helping me using that method. Thanks

Comment: the only problem with 2D arrays is that you are limited on the number of words you can read, if height of the 2D array is 10 and person inputs 11 words, then you have no way of handling that 11th word, also you dont have that 1 to 1 association with count, you can only read the words

Comment: How do I go about handling the limited amount of words though...because although I understand how 2D arrays work..I am stuck on the very basic aspect of this problem that I am to solve which is get the input, store the input as individually unique words, then increment every time you see the same word.

Comment: besides the '\n', should also check for ' ', '?', '.', ';', ':', '\t', EOF and anything else that can be used to separate one word from the next.  Then the same code could get its input from a file

Comment: The it statement takes care of that, if isalpha(input) add the character, else add '\0' which terminates that word, the outter check for '\n' is used to end the loopm

Answer (score 0):

OP still has a far amount of work ahead.

This trick is to 1) read input 2) identify delimiters 3) compare words to entire buffer and 4) print them only once.

This approach is memory efficient as it only used the 64 `char` buffer suggested by OP.  The search complexity is O(n*n)

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Helper function to find word occurrences.
void Print_count(const char *word, const char *array, int i) {
  int count = 0;
  const char *found;
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if (isalpha((unsigned char ) array[j])) {
      if (strcmp(&array[j], word) == 0) {
        found = &array[j];
        count++;
      }
      // skip rest of word
      do {
        j++;
      } while (isalpha((unsigned char ) array[j]));
    }
  }
  if (found == word) {
    printf("%s %d\n", word, count);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  char array[64];
  int i = 0;
  int j;
  int input;
  printf("Please enter an input:");

  // get the input
  while ((input = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && input != EOF) {
    array[i] = input;
    if (i + 1 >= sizeof array)
      break;
    i++;
  }
  array[i] = '\0';

  // change all delimiters to \0
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if (!isalpha((unsigned char ) array[j])) {
      array[j] = '\0';
    }
  }


  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    // Use the beginning of each word ... 
    if (isalpha((unsigned char ) array[j])) {
      Print_count(&array[j], array, i);
      // skip test of word
      do {
        j++;
      } while (isalpha((unsigned char ) array[j]));
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Input `Hello#@Hello# hs,,,he,,whywhyto`

Output:

```
Hello 2
hs 1
he 1
whywhyto 1
```